# Run two mysql process on one data directory

Tags: mysql, security, debian

I would like to launch two mysql process on one data directory (/var/lib/mysql)
I have two servers, web-01 and web-02 but web-01 locked mysql data directory, and i would like to break this security. Is it possible

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I use a shared directory to save data from web server, this directory use RAID 1 (mdadm). I created linked link like this on my two web server : ln-s  /var/lib/mysql /mnt/webfiles
I try to set up a HA Web server using haproxy with one data server and two web servers

Answer (score 2):

Deffinitely it's not. It would result in data inconsistency.

You can try to run replication; 2 instances of mysql on one server
1 master -> 1 slave; two datadirs

Comment: Ok, i'll run one mysql server on my data server. Tanks for your response :-)